# Is there an Outlook event that occurs when a user attaches a document to an email?

Tags: vba, vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm working on project to check email attachment size and it notifies the sender when they are trying to attach a large document.  I started by using example code shown at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa209975(v=office.11).aspx and it works great as described when running the sub TestAttachAdd().  However, with the code running, when I manually create a new email and attach a file to it, the AttachmentAdd event is not triggered.

Am I using the private sub "newItem_AttachmentAdd" incorrectly for what I'm trying to do?

Or is there another Outlook event that I can use to detect when a user attaches a document (either using the "attach file" ribbon button or by drag-and-drop) to a new email?

```
Public WithEvents newItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub newItem_AttachmentAdd(ByVal newAttachment As Attachment)
    If newAttachment.Type = olByValue Then
        newItem.Save
        If newItem.Size > 500 Then '500 bytes used for testing purposes only 
            MsgBox "Warning: Item size is now " & newItem.Size & " bytes."
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub TestAttachAdd()
    Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim atts As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim newAttachment As Outlook.Attachment

    Set newItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
    newItem.Subject = "Test attachment"
    Set atts = newItem.Attachments
    Set newAttachment = atts.Add("C:\Test.txt", olByValue)
End Sub
```

-------------------------- updated with most current working version 1/27/2014

```
Public WithEvents goInspectors As outlook.Inspectors
Public WithEvents newItem As outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Initialize_Handlers()
    Set goInspectors = outlook.Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_Handlers
End Sub

Private Sub goInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set newItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub newItem_AttachmentAdd(ByVal newAttachment As Attachment)
    If newAttachment.Type = olByValue Then
        newItem.Save
        If newItem.Size > 500 Then '500 bytes used for testing purposes only
            MsgBox "Warning: Item size is now " & newItem.Size & " bytes."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach your event handler to the right MailItem object.

Trap the Application.Inspectors.NewInspector event, then retrieve the new item from Inspector.CurrentItem.

Comment: Dmitry, thanks for responding to nearly all of my noob questions!  Unfortunately, I'm not exactly sure what you're saying, I think it's beyond my basic understanding of VB.  Do you have an example I can look at or point me to a website that does?  Thanks again!

Comment: I found a code snippet at http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/37778-AttachmentAdd-Event-(Outlook-2002-VBA) that shows a functioning AttachmentAdd.  But it still requires the InitializeHandler sub to be run first.  Is there a way to have this automatically run so that I can detect whenever the user tries to add an attachment?

Comment: Where does your code run? Is it a standalone app or a COM addin?

Comment: This is in VBA.  I was able to set the Inspector at Application_Startup and it works now.  Thanks, Dmitry!

Comment: Found a bug. Reposted latest version.  So, if I open a new email, start working on it, then open another email, if i switch back to the first one and try to attach a document, the size check does not work.  I think this is related to how I `Set newItem`.  Is there a way to `Set` the top most item as `newItem`?  I tried using ActiveInspector.CurrentItem, but I don't know of a way to keep it "polling" and I can't do it from within `newItem_AttachmentAdd`.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to support multiple open inspectors, you need to trap the Application.Inspectors.NewInspector  event and add Inspector.CurrentItem to a list (or array) rather than a single variable. When the Inspector.Close event fires, you will need to remove the corresponding item from the list (array) of the items that you monitor.

Comment: I don't really want to support multiple open inspectors.  I just want to be able to set the top-most draft email with the focus to be `newItem`.  I just can't seem to figure out a simple solution.

Comment: You don't have much of a choice - you will need to track all open inspectors, catch the Inspector.Activate event for all open inspectors, and reset the newItem variable.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of after finding someone who had the exact same issue at http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/catch-activate-event-any-inspector-t3389038.html. I also found the referenced example at http://www.slovaktech.com/code_samples.htm#InspectorWrapper.  Is this the preferred solution?  Or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Ken's solution is the way to go. It is as simple as it gets.

Comment: I've spent the past couple hours trying to digest what's going on with the example code at slovaktech and I'm still not sure how to use this.